# Algorithm to find the maximum sum in a sequence of overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm, sum, max, intervals

The problem I am trying to solve has a list of intervals on the number line, each with a pre-defined score. I need to return the maximum possible total score.

The catch is that the intervals overlap, and of the overlapping intervals I can use only one. Here is an example.

```
Intervals   - Score  
   0- 5     -  15  
   4- 9     -  18  
  10-15     -  12  
   8-21     -  19  
  25-30     -  25
```

Here, the intervals 0-5, 4-9 and 8-21 overlap.
The intervals 10-15 and 8-21 also overlap.
The maximum sum would be 55 (18+12+25).

It is important to note here that we select the interval 4-9 of the first batch of overlapping intervals even though it does not have the highest score of the three.

This is because selecting the interval 8-21 would prevent us from using the interval 10-15 later on, thereby reducing the overall sum (In that case, the overall sum would be 19+25=44).

I am looking for an O(nlogn) or O(n) solution to this problem. I think dynamic programming can be used, but I may be wrong. Could someone suggest a solution/algorithm(s) that could do the trick here?

Edit: The intervals are in no particular order.

Comment: I think you could use dynamic programming, but that would be O(n^2).

Comment: An explanation and implementation in C++ is [available here](http://marcodiiga.github.io/interval-scheduling/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a weighted variation of [interval scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling); it's solvable in `O(N log N)` with [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Let an interval be `g(start, stop, score)`, and let them be sorted by `stop`. For simplicity, let's assume for now that all `stop` is unique.

Let `best[i]` be the best score we can get when we're allowed to use `g[1], ..., g[i]`. We don't have to use them all, of course, and generally we can't because the subset of intervals we use must be non-overlapping.

- Clearly `best[0] = 0`. That is, since we can't use any interval, the best score we can get is 0.
- For any `1 <= k <= N`, we have:

  - `best[k] = max( best[k-1], best[j] + g[k].score )`, where

    - `j` is the largest index such that `g[j].stop < g[k].start` (`j` may be zero)

That is, given that we're allowed to use `g[1], ... g[k]`, the best we can do is the better scoring of these two options:

- We do not include `g[k]`. Thus, the score of this option is `best[k-1]`.

  - ... because that's the best we can do with `g[1], ... g[k-1]`
- We include `g[k]`, and to its left we do the best we can with all the genes that don't overlap with `g[k]`, i.e. all `g[1], ..., g[j]`, where `g[j].stop < g[k].start` and `j` is as large as possible. Thus, the score of this option is `best[j] + g[k].score`.

(Note the optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems components of dynamic programming embodied in the above equation).

The overall answer to the question is `best[N]`, i.e. the best score we can get when we're allowed to use all the genes. Oops, did I say genes? I mean intervals.

This is `O(N log N)` because:

- Sorting all the intervals takes `O(N log N)`
- Finding `j` for each `k` is `O(log N)` using binary search

---

If several genes can have the same `stop` values, then nothing changed: you still have to search for the rightmost `j`. In e.g. Python this is easy with [`bisect_right`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html). In Java where the standard library binary search doesn't guarantee which index is returned in case of ties, you can (among many options) follow it with a linear search (for `O(N)` worst-case performance), or another series of binary searches to find the right most index.

Oops did I say genes again? I mean intervals.

#### Related questions

- [Extension of binary search to find the first and last index of the key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218931/extension-of-binary-search-algo-to-find-the-first-and-last-index-of-the-key-value)

Comment: And yes, I passed the bot. Wink-wink.

Comment: +1: Seems right (even with negative scores). Not sure why I was thinking O(n^2) is the best known for this. Will delete my answer.

Comment: It has to be noted that "Finding j for each k is O(log N) using binary search" is not accurate. Complexity is actually O(n log n) for the whole operation. We iterate over 1..j i.e. O(n), and then for each iteration we have a binary search O(log n). Since when n grows both O(n) and O(log n) functions are affected, the overall complexity is bound by O(n) * O(log n) = O(n log n).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I think the maximum is 59, not 55. If you choose intervals [0-5],[8-21], and [25,30], you get 15+19+25=59. You can use some sort of dynamic programming to handle this.

First, you sort all the intervals by their starting point, then iterate from end to start. For each item in list, you choose the maximum sum from that point to the last as `max(S[i]+S[j], S[i+1])`, where i is the item you are on, j is the item that is the first non-overlapping entry following your item (that is, the first item whose start is larger than the current item's end). To speed up the algorithm, you want to store the maximum partial sum S[j] for each element.

To clarify, let me solve your example according to this. First, sort your intervals:

```
 1:  0- 5 -  15
 2:  4- 9 -  18
 3:  8-21 -  19
 4: 10-15 -  12
 5: 25-30 -  25
```

So,

```
 S[5] = 25
 S[4] = max(12+S[5], 25)=37
 S[3] = max(19+S[5], S[4])=max(19+25,37)=44
 S[2] = max(18+S[4], S[3])=max(18+37,44)=55
 S[1] = max(15+S[3], S[2])=max(15+44, 55)=59
```

This is an adaptation of the algorithm in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243234/algorithm-to-find-the-maximum-sum-in-a-sequence-of-overlapping-intervals/3243280#3243280), but unfortunately, doesn't have the nice O(n) running time. A degenerate list where each entry overlaps the next would cause it to be O(n^2).

Comment: @vhallac Why is it the j is decremented in line 4 (At S[2]) but not at line 3 (At S[3]). Any particular reason?

Comment: @vhallac Correct me if I am wrong. We can sort the intervals in `O(n log n)` then for each interval we can find the first non-overlapping interval using binary-search thus requiring `O(n log n)`. Then we use your algorithm and for each `i` we already know the `j` calculated using binary-search. Thus total time is `O(n log n) + O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this a bit and came up with something.

[Interval Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) provide an efficient way of finding all the intervals that overlap a given interval. Walking through the entire set of intervals, we can find all the overlapping intervals for a given one. Once we have these, we can find the interval with the highest score, store it and move on.

Building the tree takes O(N Log N) time and lookup takes O(Log N) time. Because we do a lookup for all elements, the solution becomes O(N Log N).

However, if we face something like the example above where the highest score interval in one group reduces the total, the algorithm fails because we have no way of knowing that the highest score interval should not be used before hand. The obvious way around this would be to calculate both (or all) totals in case we are not sure, but that puts us back to a potentially O(N^2) or worse solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an approach like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584228/algorithm-to-find-the-maximum-subsequence-of-an-array-of-positive-numbers-catch/584343#584343) could be used, which is *O(n)* at least for that problem. It would mean to iterate once through the intervals and keep track of just those interval combinations that still could lead to an optimal final solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can use this recursion...

`S[i]` denotes the score of each interval
`Interval[i]` denotes all the intervals

```
ResMax[i] = max(ResMax[i-1] + S[i] //if i is included
           ,max(R[i-1],S[i]) 
         )
```

I am not checked thoroughly but it should work i beleive.