# Find path with least weight from a bunch of possible paths

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I needed some help/pointers on a homework problem. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction on how to go about solving this problem :)

## Assignment

> "An angry bird named Mo is flying a long journey to exact his revenge
>   on the pigs.  To  save energy for the fight, the bird will take
>   advantage of jet streams that will lower his flying energy
>   consumption.  Before the flight, BirdHQ gave the bird an input file in
>   the following format:
>
> 1. First line contains only 1 integer, which is the constant energy it takes to fly 1 mile WITHOUT jet streams.
> 2. Every subsequent line contains 3 space-separated integers: the start mile marker of the jet stream, the end mile marker of the jet
>      stream, and lastly an integer denoting the overall energy needed to
>      fly that jet stream’s distance.
>
> For instance, the line “3 7 12″ means it takes 12 energy units to fly
>   the 4 miles between miles 3 and 7.
>
> Note that jet streams can overlap, but the bird cannot be on more than
>   one jet stream at a time, and it cannot fly partial jet streams.
>
> For simplicity, consider the end mile marker of the farthest jet
>   stream as the end of the journey.
>
> Write a python program that takes in an input file “jetstreams.txt” to
>   plan out the optimal sequence of jet streams Mo should fly on to
>   minimize his energy consumption throughout the entire journey.  All
>   integers in the input file are non-negative.  As output, print out the
>   mininum total energy and a list of tuples denoting the jet streams’
>   endpoints.
>
> For example, given the sample jetstreams.txt, the minimum total energy
>   needed to fly all 24 miles is 352 energy units, and the optimal
>   sequence of jet streams is [(0,5), (6,11), (14,17), (19,24)]."

### jetstreams.txt

```
50
0 5 10
1 3 5
3 7 12
6 11 20
14 17 8
19 24 14
21 22 2
```

Would this be anything like solving the shortest path of a graph?

Comment: +1 for homework problem involving angry birds.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit that moved the bulk of the question to an external site. 1) People generally won't follow external links, 2) The questions here should be self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You have a "don't use the jetstream at all" path, which consists of vertices numbered 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24. The edges which join each of these vertices has a "weight" of 50* the distance - so the 0->1 edge is weighted 50, the 1->3 edge is weighted 100, etc.

Then, you have additional edges representing the jetstreams - one from 0->5 weighted 10, one from 1->3 weighted 5, etc.

Together, these form a directed acyclic graph (a DAG).

Now you have that, you can apply the usual graph traversal techniques to find the "cheapest" route from vertex 0 to vertex 24.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a shortest path problem, with energy substituted for the length of each edge.  When constructing the graph of the sample problem, start out with a straight line from 0 to 24, with a 50 energy unit cost for each mile.  Then draw in the jet stream edges and their energy consumption to complete the graph.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily expressed as a Minimum weighted interval scheduling algorithm.
Each jetstream is an interval with a weight, and the goal is to choose intervals that minimize the weight.

See the following links for Maximum weighted interval scheduling or google to learn more: 
You can replace the `max` calculations to `min` for your problem.

[Algorithm to find the best combination of items under certain constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800226/algorithm-to-find-the-best-combination-of-items-under-certain-constraints/8920088#8920088)

[Weighted Interval Scheduling problem & Dynamic program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574986/weighted-interval-scheduling-problem-dynamic-program)