# Activity selection greedy approach (modified)

Tags: algorithm, greedy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to find the maximum sum in a sequence of overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243234/algorithm-to-find-the-maximum-sum-in-a-sequence-of-overlapping-intervals)

I was solving the following  modified activity scheduling (Greedy approach) problem :

Given a set S of n activities with and start time, **Si** and **fi**, finish time of an **ith** activity. Also given weight **wi** ,*the cost earned by Foo for doing ith activities*.

The problem is to select the activities that **maximizes foo earnings**. We have to return the maximum cost that can be earn  by foo.*Assume that Foo can only work on a single activity at a time*.

Note::

This is similar to classic [Activity selection problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem)  ,here the only difference is ,for each activities ,we are given a cost wi . And the goal here is too different -*Instead of finding   maximum size set of mutually compatible activities* ,In this problem we have to find set of those activities that maximise foo total earnings .

Example

```
Total activities N=4
Si fi wi
0 1 4000
2 5 100
1 4 3000
4 5 2500

Max earning=9500 (Answer)
```

How do i modify the classical greedy activity selection  algorithm ,for solving this problem . What logic should i use to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see how to solve this greedily. The solution I can see is dynamic programming, in which you have to solve the subproblem

F(n) = what is the maximum profit that Foo can get by working only after day n?

Then the recursive formulation is clear: We have that F(n) is either equal to F(n+1) (in the case in which Foo doesn't work on day n), or equal to the maximum out of F(fi) + wi, for each activity that starts on time si=n .

EDIT: Suppose the ending times of the activities are f0 <= f1 <= f2 <= ... <= fN. Then the answer is F[f0] (what is the best profit working starting on time f0), and it can be calculated as:

```
for n = N to 0:
    F[fn] = F[fn+1]
    for each activity (si, fi, wi):
         if si == fn: 
             F[fn] = max(F[fn], F[fi] + wi)
```

If the activities are sorted in non-increasing order based on their starting time, the complexity of this approach is linear in the number of activities (as you can stop the inner loop when si < N).

Comment: Thankyou !!!!Hi ,i am not able to understand properly , can you please provide pseudo-code ?

Comment: I think , the above dp wont work. It even fails for the above  example.

Comment: I think it will. F[5] = 0, F[4] = max(F[5], F[5]+2500) = 2500, F[2] = max(F[4], F[5] + 100)=2500, F[1] = max(F[2], F[4] + 3000) = 5500, F[0] = max(F[1], F[1] + 4000) = 9500. Try to understand things before you say they don't work.